# Trying to Search and Replace - Eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse, search, replace

I am trying to use regular expression in IBM RAD / eclipse to search and replace entire code base/Java Web Project(jsp, java) of specific matching crieria.

What I am trying to do is, I am searching for

```
method(string, string)
```

and to replace it with

```
method(string, string, string) // adding additional argument.
```

For Example:

```
method("Employee", "Language")
method("Customer", "Lang");
```

I want to replace all `method(*,*,"TOKEN");`

I have searched like `method(*,*)` and returns all, but while trying to replace `method(*, *, TOKEN)`, it is replacing as "*"...any help..not that much familiar with regular expression..already searched many threads and still searching..any help would be greatful..thanks

Comment: is it a java method? if so then use the refactor option to change the signature of the method

Comment: It is java mehod. But not newly introduced method..being referred in the jar (third party)..only class files are there...

Answer (score 1):

if you select the methodname e.g:

```
public void getAngle(){..}
```

and you select ´getAngle()´ and press ´alt+shift+c´ , you should be able to modify the method signature